How to handle (elegantly) an empty group by expression
consider this code
    <xsl:variable name="sequence" select="
                  ( map { 'foo' : 1, 'bar' : () },
                    map { 'foo' : 1, 'bar' : () },
                    map { 'foo' : 1, 'bar' : '3' } )" as="map(xs:string,item()*)*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="distinct" as="map(xs:string,item()*)*">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$sequence" group-by="map:get(.,'bar')">
            <xsl:sequence select="map { 'group' : current-grouping-key() }"/>            
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:variable>

I want the result to be
 ( map { 'group' : () }
   map { 'group' : 3  } )

but it gives me
 ( map { 'group' : 3  } )

(which I actually find a little odd)
how can you elegantly handle the above in XSLT?
(I've tried wrapping the group expression in an array, but it secretly maps that to a sequence and then discards it as empty, and maps don't work in group-by expressions)

I think this works
    <xsl:variable name="sequence" select="
                  ( map { 'foo' : 1, 'bar' : () },
                    map { 'foo' : 1, 'bar' : () },
                    map { 'foo' : 1, 'bar' : '3' } )" as="map(xs:string,item()*)*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="distinct" as="map(xs:string,item()*)*">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$sequence" group-by="map:get(.,'bar')" composite="true">
            <xsl:sequence select="map { 'group' : current-grouping-key() }"/>            
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:variable>

i.e. if composite is set to true, then () is not thrown away as a key.
https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#xsl-for-each-group

If composite="yes" is specified, there will be a single grouping key, which will in general be a sequence of zero or more atomic values; otherwise, there will be zero or more grouping keys, each of which will be a single atomic value.


The issue with group-by is that you could have maps not having a bar property and that an empty sequence key doesn't constitute an item belonging to a group.
So with grouping I think you would rather elaborately and a bit hackishly have to check for the existence of an empty sequence as the map value, for the group-by "map" it to some atomic value (I used EMPTY)) and then for your computed result map sequence "map" that back to an empty sequence:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:variable name="sequence" select="
                  ( map { 'foo' : 1, 'bar' : () },
                    map { 'foo' : 1, 'bar' : () },
                    map { 'foo' : 1, 'bar' : '3' } )" as="map(xs:string,item()*)*"/>

  <xsl:output method="adaptive"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$sequence" group-by="if (map:contains(., 'bar')) then if (not(empty(map:get(., 'bar')))) then map:get(., 'bar') else 'EMPTY' else ()">
            <xsl:sequence select="map { 'group' : if (current-grouping-key() eq 'EMPTY') then () else current-grouping-key() }"/>            
        </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Perhaps someone else later comes up with something more elegant.

its clunky though isn't it...this is the sort of thing I was hoping to avoid, no offence.

does the same issue exist in 4.0 do you know? is it worth having an option on group-by that doesnt ignore () as a key?

actually if you set composite to true, then it basically does work...I'll post an answer

I would concatenate the map key and value, to ensure that even when the value is () it has a value to group-by. Then do the group-by, and then remove the key from the grouped value:
<xsl:variable name="distinct" as="map(xs:string,item()*)*">
  <xsl:variable name="key" select="'bar'"/>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="$sequence" group-by="$key||map:get(.,$key)">
    <xsl:sequence select="map { 'group' : substring-after(current-grouping-key(), $key) }"/>            
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:variable>

Instead of concatenating the key and value, which would make everything a string, you could provide a sequence of values as the grouping-key with the map value as the first and the default value as the second. It will use the first value in the sequence that isn't an empty sequence as the key, and then test if the current-grouping-key() is that default value or not and exclude if it is:
<xsl:variable name="distinct" as="map(xs:string,item()*)*">
  <xsl:variable name="key" select="'bar'"/>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="$sequence" group-by="(map:get(.,$key), $key)">
    <xsl:sequence select="map { 'group' : current-grouping-key()[not(deep-equal(. ,$key))] }"/>            
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:variable>


yep, I've sort if done this sort of thing in the past, I was hoping there was something that didn't require me to map the value out into some string value, only to then have to map it back.

it's either that, or use a default alternate value as Martin suggests. The problem is that in the XSLT context, an empty sequence is seen as "nothing" and not holding the spot in the group-by.

yes, this is what I find odd, () is a valid value, but if it's a key, its somehow equated to invalid as a key, and you cant wrap it in anything in the language (like an array) without it being coerced back to a sequence and thus back to "None"

does your solution group '()' with '""'?

actually if you set composite to true, then it basically does work...I'll post an answer
